# Windows UI in pharo

Tags: pharo

I'm pretty green when it comes to Pharo, so I ask you apologies in advance for what might be a dumb question.

I would like to know if there is a way to configure Pharo with the look and feel of native desktop windows applications, or at least to move the minimize-maximize-close buttons to the right corner.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not. There is work in progress (specifically [OSWindow](http://smalltalkhub.com/#!/~Pharo/OSWindow)) but it will be some time before we make that transition.

Comment: Thank you very much! I'm new to Pharo, so my opinion doesn't count, but I think that being always stuck in your own graphical interface makes any development feel a bit isolated.

Comment: Of course your opinion counts. Even more so as long time users lack that outside view you have. As I said, we're certainly trying to move into the direction of native widgets.